{DURING INSTALLATION} kernel panic - not syncing attempted to kill init exitcode=0x00007f00
LOG
( No experience with Linux btw )
( I have windows 7 installed )
( BIOS not UEFI )
EDIT
( DESKTOP )
( Trying to Install Jammy Jellifish )
I am using Ventoy, so I am just copy pasting the ISO file to the pendrive
I checked byte size on my hard disk and the pendrive, they are the same
I don't know how to perform checksum
EDIT 2
ventoy has built in checksum tool so I was reading about it in their website and they had mentioned that make sure to eject the pendrive after copy is complete, however I was just restarting the computer and boot into the usb thinking it ejects the pendrive on its own, i ejected properly and now it is working, I still have install ubuntu alongside windows missing but I think it would be best to open a new question as it this may mislead the title of this question. thank you
So I am trying to install Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish but getting hit by this error while trying to boot it from an USB.
The following paragraph maybe useless, idk
Actually, initially I was trying to install Ubuntu Noble Numbat however, firstly I had used Etcher For Windows 7 and I tried Ubuntu for an hour or two then I decided to install it however I was thrown an error so then I tried Unetbootin and it allowed me to go further into the installation however that too gave an error later on in the installation after selecting my location then I was surfing the web about it and I came across multiple pages recommending to not install Noble Numbat yet so then I wanted to install Jammy Jellifish.
I made a bootable USB of Jammy Jellifish using Unetbootin but I was not getting the "install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option even when turning off fast boot ( and there was no secure boot in my BIOS ) and also tried to manually partition using Window's partition tool however I failed in that too as my Unallocated space was not showing up as free space, I tried creating a new Volume for installing Ubuntu but still failed as partitions were showing up in weird manner ( I don't remember correctly but the Windows 7 Partition was showing up as within 10 MB )
So I tried Etcher again but no luck and my pendrive was being shrunk to around 4 GB from 16 GB so I was using diskpart to fix it but this time IDK WHY but I tried deleting partitions from Windows partition tool but it didn't work as I had expected so I used diskpart to do things as I had done.
I tried using Ventoy but now I was getting this error which is mentioned in the title of this question so I thought like, maybe Ventoy unable to function properly so I tried Unetbootin again but I was getting the same thing, so I tried Ventoy again, no luck, I had moved Ubuntu ISO from C drive to D drive right before installing Ventoy because some people had said that Ubuntu installer won't give "install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager" option so I thought maybe my ISO got damaged somehow while moving so I downloaded ISO again but still no luck so I also tried Noble Numbat with Ventoy but it was working the same as it had with Unetbootin
btw I was getting this during boot and shutdown of Noble Numbat, "can't find TOCBLOCK, database may be corrupt"

Please be complete with details... I take it you are trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy), but also mention 24.04 (noble).. but no mention of what product (Server? Desktop?) or what installer is being used (they can differ; selected by ISO downloaded). You don't mention performing any checks (ISO checksum, diff or comparison of written ISO on media & downloaded ISO) as well, so I'm unsure what you're currently using..  Your error can be procedural; you didn't use correct software options on ISO write, or invalid ISO etc.. & other things too, thus checks are in my opinion essential.

You can not just copy the ISO and have it work, you need to make a bootable thumb drive with an installed copy of the ISO on it.  Some steps for you to review and follow. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview
